# How to upload large file using python to elasticsearch with most efficient way?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to upload about 40gb of data to elasticsearch. It's is in json format, because there is a lot of data and computer could not load file, I'm unable to give structure of file to elasticsearch, that way it using dynamical definition of structure.

Because of dynamic definition it use precious memory, but uploading 40gb also not an easy task. I left script to run for night and in morning discovered that is still running (it was uploading about 12h+ and still didn't upload). Below is shown how upload is made. I know that it is not the best way, because it iterates through all line, but i didn't came up with anything else.

```py
import os
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(
    ['elasticsearch'],
    port=9200

)

raiseFieldLimit = '''
{  
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 10000
}'''

es.indices.create(index=os.environ.get('INDEX'), body=raiseFieldLimit)

i=0
f = open("test", "r")
for x in f:
    string_for_output = x.decode('utf-8').strip()
    es.index(index=os.environ.get('INDEX'), doc_type='Data', id=i, body=string_for_output)
    i=i+1
```

So the main question, is there any other way how to make upload of 40gb file faster and no to wait for 12h+?

Comment: I would definitely use the [python bulk helpers](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#bulk-helpers) to load your data in bulk instead of line by line

Comment: Why not use Logstash? It´s a simple pipeline and it will be more efficient than building a script, even if you use bulk in your script.

Comment: also checkout using the [flattened](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/flattened.html) data type as a way to remove the need to increase the field limit and reduce indexing costs